# Advice on onPause and onResume

Tags: java, android

If i use the code below will this restore text that has been input into EditTextfields and selected spinner items?

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){ 
        super.onPause();

    }


    @Override 
    protected void onResume(){ 
        super.onResume(); 

    }
```

or do I have to tell it to save the current values and then restore then when activity is resumed? when I am using the emulator if I don't have these methods in and I go to say home then run my app again it always loads back to the previous state, so my questions is does this actually do antyhing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this actually only called the super class onPause() and onResume() without doing anything else. The value in your editbox stay there because even if the app is paused, is still there on the activity stack waiting. 
However Android can kill your paused activity and your data will be lost. So you have to save them onPause and restore them on the onResume to avoid this.

Comment: thats fine as this app only needs to run on memory, no need to restore states in that way

Comment: If you don't need to restore states, it's ok. But you need to know that Android can kill a paused activity on its own, in order to free memory. Then your app will not be resumed, it will be started again, with no previously entered data. Android however, before destroying your app call the onDestroy method which let you addressing the event as you wish

Comment: @nax83 No, you shouldn't do your state saving in onDestroy. Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29): "do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!"

Comment: @kabuko you are right! I was thinking about the onDestroy and I wrote it, but its the onPause. Thx

Answer (score 1):

No, this code does not do anything. You're overriding these methods, but giving them an implementation of just calling the parent implementation. This is the same as not overriding them in the first place.

It's not absolutely necessary to save/restore state for when you pause/resume. The only reason why you would need to manually do some state saving is if you want to restore state even after your application is killed.

Comment: so if say the user was in the procces of adding something to a database and the activity closed in error then something would need to be done here.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be an error. If the user leaves your application to do something else, Android may kill your application to free memory. In this case, the current state will be lost unless you previously saved it.

Comment: if your `Activity` closes because of an error you will not be able to restore its state.  You should ensure that you catch any exception that may occur so that you can handle it with out the activity force closing.

Answer (score 0):

You values still the same in your spinner because the app hasn't been kill yet. It's only put a pause state still in memory. If the app were destroyed the values of your spinner will be back to the onCreate method and whatever value they had at the start.

Look here for what each method does --> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

You only need to save state when `onDestroy()` is called.  That only happens when you use the back button or the OS kills the `Activity` when it is in a stopped state.

If you `Activity` becomes partially obscured it will be paused but if it is completely obscured it will be stopped.

When it is top of the stack again it will resume or start.

To experiment use `Log` to write messages to the `LogCat` when each of events occurs and then you will be able to see when and why they are called.

Comment: No, you should not rely on saving state in onDestroy. As I commented on another answer, the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) say: "do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!"

Comment: I know, they say to save state in onPause.